Screenshots are in RAM (Not on Disk!) as BMP, which slows down things when pasting screenshots in chats. How can I change default format?
For my job as a student supervisor, during 90% of the time I spend on Teams with students I share screenshots of plots or anything I have on my screen, and they do the same to me. We do Win-Shift-S and then Ctrl-V in a chat. Occasionally I use also Whatsapp. Problem is: image takes long to load, and if I click enter to quick it doesnt load in Teams and people received it like the image below. it is a pain, from what I read online seems that by default they are saved IN MEMORY as BMP. Is there a way to have screenshot saved in memory as JPG or other compressed format, so it can be Crtl-V-ed  quickly in the chat? I would prefer not to have to download a snippet tool, but if that is the only way to solve the problem I can do that. I like Win-Shift-S, so handy, no notification and quick.


Is there a way? has a yes answer almost always

try writing a script that does the job

I can tell you that i have the same isssue in teams (at least for the last few months) but I use Snagit, so the screen captures are already saved on disk as files prior to attempting to paste them into Teams. I've generally found that if i wait 3 seconds before clicking send, the images are much more likely to go through correctly. I do however think your premise that the image not being stored on disk is the problem probably isn't correct.
